# Timestamp conversion in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am converting timestamp to date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` and I am using `America/New_York` as `TimeZone`. Whenever I convert the timestamp into the date it shows one hour less than usual date and time. How to resolve this in java?

Here's the code:

```
  String timestamp = "1431941838000";
  long time = Long.valueOf(timestamp);
  Date currentDate = new Date(time);
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

  TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
  df.setTimeZone(zone);
  String finale = df.format(currentDate);
```

Comment: What does the input value `1431941838000` represent? Is it a number of milliseconds since the epoch (01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT)?

Comment: What's the `usual` date and time? Do you mean it's less than you would expect it?

Comment: Also I would suggest you to look at the java 8 date and time API. Classes like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to using `EST` to replace `America/New_York` like

`TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");`

**Updated**

It's My Test code:

```
    String timestamp = "1431941838000";
    long time = Long.valueOf(timestamp);
    Date currentDate = new Date(time);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    TimeZone zoneNewYork = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    df.setTimeZone(zoneNewYork);
    String finale = df.format(currentDate);
    System.out.println(finale);

    TimeZone zoneEst = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
    df.setTimeZone(zoneEst);
    finale = df.format(currentDate);
    System.out.println(finale);
```

And My result as bellow:

```
    2015-05-18 05:37:18.000
    2015-05-18 04:37:18.000
```

Comment: EST also gives the same result

Comment: @wazza Your excepted result is "2015-05-18 06:37:18.000" ?

Comment: My expected value for the above timestamp is  2015-05-18 04:37:18.000

Comment: plz Refer this link  [link] (http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=-5.5&timestamp=1431941838000&Submit=++++++Convert+to+Date++++++)

Comment: @wazza is daylight savings time issue, `timezone.getDSTSavings()` ?

Comment: when I use EST I am getting the correct date time and I have a quer reg this. Is this will work for all the dates in the year

Comment: EST mean Eastern Standard Time, I think it will work for all the dates

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra point in this line:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").;
//                                                      ^ here!!!
```

**UPDATE**
 if you dont get any error, the output must be the correct:
`EST` is `UTC` - 5 hours. `America/New_York` is `EST` **in the winter** and `E*D*T` **in the summer**, so check if `String timestamp = "1431941838000";` is winter or summer...

This code works ok:

```
Calendar calNewYork = Calendar.getInstance();
calNewYork.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("Time in New York: " + calNewYork.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
    + calNewYork.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Use this to check your time:

```
long timestamp = "1431941838000";
Calendar calNewYork = Calendar.getInstance();
calNewYork.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
calNewYork.setTime(new Date(timestamp));
System.out.println("Time in New York: " + calNewYork.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
    + calNewYork.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: No. I am getting 1 hour behind the usual time